# Move largest char to the front

Tags: c, string, loops

The code accepts a character string str as parameter, finds the largest character from the string, and moves it to the beginning of the string.

```
Example 1 (Single instance of large char)
Input: adebc
Output:eadbc

Example 2 (Multiple instance of large char)
Input: agfcdeg 
Output:gafcdeg
```

Code

```
void maxCharToFront(char *str)
{
int large, i = 0;
char first;
large = str[i];

/* Find largest character */
while (str[i] != '\0')
{
    if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') ||
        (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            if (str[i] > large)
            {
                large = str[i];
            }
        }
        i++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    str[i] = str[i+1];

/*Move largest character to the front*/
first = str[0];
str[0]=large;
str[1] = first;
}
```

However instead of moving the largest char to the front it and leaving the rest intact, my code merely replaces the first character with the code.

`Input: adebc
Current output:eebc`

How do I improve this?

Comment: Make not only a note of the largest char but also of its position/index. Then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following suggestions:

1. *You just need to store the position of largest char.*
2. *2nd for loop does not always need to loop till the end of the string.*
3. *You don't need to swap the first and largest char since you have adjusted the string, you can directly store the largest char in 0th location.*

Sample code

```
void maxCharToFront(char *str)
{
 int  i = 0;
 int pos=0;

 /* Find largest character */
 while (str[i] != '\0')
 {
    if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') ||
        (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            if (str[i] > str[pos])
            {

                pos = i;
            }
        }
        i++;
 }

 char large = str[pos];

 for(int i = pos; i > 0; i--)
    str[i] = str[i-1];

  str[0] = large;

}
```